# how to avoid exe.manifest and exe.config in my build

Tags: .net, winforms

I am developing winform app. I want to use the Exe I get inside the \bin\Release to run my app. But each time I build the app I get two extra files with extensions  exe.manifest and exe.config inside Release folder. If i run my exe file with out these files it won't work. Is there any way to remove it from build? so that I can use only my exe file to run the app??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The applicationName.exe.config file contains the application settings of your application and in case you have app.config file in you application, this file will be created. And if application is using these configurations, your application will break if you remove this file.

To remove the .manifest file, you can go -

Project Properties >> Debug and Uncheck Enable the visual studio hosting process.